# Clean second selectOneMenu when choose first element on first selectOneMenu

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces, converters, selectonemenu

I have 2 selectOneMenu, second one is depend on first. When I choose an element on first, the second select load right, but I want to clean the second select (and other elements) when I choose default element, `Seleccione marca`, on first select. I'm using converter. The code:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="marcas" value="#{adminBean.marca}" converter="categoriaConverter" required="true">
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione marca" itemValue="" />
  <f:selectItems value="#{categoriaBean.marcas}" var="cat" itemLabel="#{cat.nombre}" itemValue="#{cat}" />
  <p:ajax listener="#{adminBean.loadTipos}" update="tipos" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
<p:selectOneMenu id="tipos" value="#{adminBean.tipo}" converter="categoriaConverter" required="true">
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione tipo" itemValue="" />
  <f:selectItems value="#{adminBean.tipos}" var="tip" itemLabel="#{tip.nombre}" itemValue="#{tip}" />
  <p:ajax listener="#{adminBean.loadProductos}" update=":formTablaProductos" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

This is my categoriaConverter:

```
@FacesConverter(value = "categoriaConverter")
public class CategoriaConverter implements Converter {

  CategoriaBeanLocal categoriaBean = lookupCategoriaBeanLocal();

  @Override
  public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
    Categoria categoria = null;
    if (value != null && !value.equals("") && !value.contains("Seleccione"))
      categoria = categoriaBean.findByIdCategoria(Integer.valueOf(value));
    return categoria;
  }

  @Override
  public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    String salida = null;
    if (value != null && !value.equals("") && !value.equals("0"))
      salida = String.valueOf(((Categoria)value).getIdCategoria());
    return salida;
  }

  private CategoriaBeanLocal lookupCategoriaBeanLocal() {
    try {
      Context c = new InitialContext();
      return (CategoriaBeanLocal) c.lookup("java:global/TiendaOnline/TiendaOnline-ejb/CategoriaBean!ejb.CategoriaBeanLocal");
    } catch (NamingException ne) {
      Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "exception caught", ne);
      throw new RuntimeException(ne);
    }
  }
}
```

`lookupCategoriaBeanLocal()` was autogenerated using `Call Enterprise Bean` in NetBeans. As can be seen, I compare value in `getAsObject` with 'Seleccione', that's the itemLabel in my first selectOneMenu, I don't know why send that.

More code, this is my `loadTipos()`:

```
public void loadTipos() {
  if (marca != null) {
    tipos = categoriaBean.findByIdCategoriaPadre(marca.getIdCategoria());
  } else {
    tipos.clear();
  }
}
```

The thing is that when I choose `Seleccione marca` don't get to `loadTipos()`, and nothing is updated, and I don't know why. Anyone can see the problem?

Greetings.